# Pass control from view to an action result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csv

I have attempted to create a file control and when user selects a .csv file, I intent to write the contents of csv file to a string.

I have a file upload control,

```
<input type = "file" onchange = "ProcessCsv()" />
```

I defined an action result in my controller

```
[HttpPost]

public ActionResult ProcessCsv(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
// Need to read the csv file into a string
}
```

I get an error saying, "Reference Error: ProcessCsv() is not defined".

How do I pass the control from html to an action result?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to submit in a form.

In your view:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("ProcessCsv", "YourControllerGoesHere", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data"})))
{
      <input type = "file" name="file" id="file"/><br/>
      <input type = "submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

Comment: thank you Michael! I have one doubt, the View has a lot of controls and I am doing numerous AJAX calls to controller to consume WCF services. Would these calls be affected if I use this @using statement? Also, can I add this "@include" just for the file upload control? I mean,can i place the code you just wrote anywhere in my view or does it need to be at the beginning and every line in that view needs to be within that @using? how does it work? please clarify

Comment: I was going on the assumption that you were using ASP .NET Razor Engine..You can replace the Using statement with a simple form like `<form action="/YourControllerGoesHere/ProcessCsv" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">...</form>`